# Can't open specific website in android browser

Tags: android, networking, browser, web, android-browser

I can't access my website in any android device.
I test access my website in any android's browser (Dolphin,Firefox,Chrome) and the result is
"Web page not available". (I access on android 4.0 4.1 2.2 and 2.3 and I have the same problem)
I install terminal in andriod and try nslookup&ping command to diagnostic. The result is not found domain name.
When I change the network, my android can normally access the website 
My own website is http://www.delisoft.co.th.
I can access my website from my PC in every browser (Chrome,Firefox,IE).
I can access my website from iOS device too.
All of device is connect with same network. I'm not found any solution from internet
Someone please help me.

Thank you.

Comment: What error are you getting ??

Comment: Try putting some code here, check for the appropriate permissions in the Manifest, ensure you have a valid internet connection. Does this happen for this web page only or for each and every one you try to open?

Comment: The error is "Web page not available" in browser
and get 'can't resolve 'www.delisoft.co.th' when I run 'nslookup www.delisoft.co.th'
This error is occur when I access www.delisoft.co.th. It not happen with other website.

Comment: It seems that you have these connectivity issues when you are in one specific network ... That is not subject to Android dev (since you cannot access the website neither from browser). You should check with ITSupport that manages the network in trouble as it may be down or something related.

Comment: @gunar I log in to my router admin page. Restricted site is not set. what shoud I do? thank you.

Comment: can you access any web page from your network or none?

Comment: @gunar In same network, other PC, MAC, and iOS device can access this website. All android devices in same network can't access only this website. It's very confuse me. All device can access other website like facebook google microsoft.

Comment: Then it's a network hardware issue, not an application/software specific. Your IT manager should be able to fix this ...

Comment: Thank you all.
I already solve my problem.
I just go to computer mart and buy new router, replace this and anything work well.